# Spring doesnt display images when there is a path variable on URI

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have a method in my controller that directs to the page with comments.
All comments are related to a specific message. I use pathvariable to send messageID that I later use to get comments from my database.

```
  @GetMapping("/showComments/{messageId}")
    public String displayComments(@PathVariable Long messageId, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user, Model model) {

 List<Comment> comments = commentService.showComments(messageId);
 Message messageGotById = messageService.getMessageById(messageId);
           
    model.addAttribute("comments", comments);
    model.addAttribute("messageGot",messageGotById);
    model.addAttribute("userId",user.getId());

        return "listComments";
    }
```

And then I have a method for fetching images from  database

```
        @GetMapping("/getImageComment/{id}")
    public void showCommentImage(@PathVariable Long id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

       
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        Message messageImage = messageService.getMessageById(id);
        ImageInfo imageInfo = messageImage.getUsr().getImageInfo();


        byte[] imageData = imageInfo.getImageData();
        String encode = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageData);

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
        IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    }
```

listComments.html

```
 <img th:src="@{'getImageComment/' + ${userId}}" height="55"
          width="55">
```

Added the link I use to go to listComments.html

```
    <a th:href="@{/showComments/{id}(id=${message.id})}">comment</a>
```

The issue here is that when there is a variable on URI in displayComments method, images are not displayed.
But without pathvariable everything works just fine.I cant understand what is the problem.

Comment: If you look at the generated HTML in your browser, does it look correct there?

Comment: It does- only images are not displayed.

Comment: Btw,controller method responsible for fetching images is not even triggered. i used simple "sout" to check it.

Comment: You should check if you need to use an absolute url `th:src="@{'/getImageComment/' + ${userId}}"` here instead of a relative url.

Comment: It doesnt work either

Comment: @buchs, does your app use any security? If it does, make sure that the user has the right privilages to access the resource in question.

Comment: It does.I checked the roles - evrythings seems okay. Anyway the page "listComments" is diplayed - only images are not.

Comment: When I modify "displayComments" method like this(drop variable from URI) -   @GetMapping("/showComments") - everything works fine, images are displayed. They are not displayed only when I add variable to the URI. And I cant get why it happens like this

Comment: @buchs, hit F12 in your browser and check what response statuses (under the Network tab) you get when you try to load comments/images. This should at least give you some idea as to why your controller method isn't even called.

Comment: This is what i see -                                                                                                Request URL: http ://localhost:8080/createMessageForm/getImageComment/10
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: @buchs, 404 means "not found". Is that correct url? Shoudn't it perhaps be `http ://localhost:8080/getImageComment/10` ? Or is the mapping for /createMessageForm placed at class level?

Comment: I dont have this url at class level in my app. The correct url is "/showComments/{messageId}"   and then "/getImageComment/{id}" must be triggered to fetch images. But it somehow generates this joined url. The first path variable confuses browser in some way

Comment: @buchs, perhaps this may help https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#context-relative-urls Try using server relative urls instead, at least in this case.

Comment: changed  th:src="@{'getImageComment/' + ${userId}}" to  th:src="@{'~/getImageComment/' + ${userId}}" and It finally worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Followed [dsp_user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1119161/dsp-user) advice and used [Server-relative URLs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#context-relative-urls). Changed

```
  <img th:src="@{'getImageComment/' + ${userId}}" height="55"
          width="55">
```

to

```
  <img class="rounded" th:src="@{'~/getImageComment/' + ${userId}}" height="55"
                                 width="55">
```

And It finally worked for me.